# Import Google Image Link into Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, import, google-drive-api

I work a lot with Google Sheets and I need some help with a script.

- I would like to create a script that can import the google file links from a google drive into my google sheet.
- It would be a script that needs to run automatically (if possible) or everytime something changes in the sheet.
- The files in the Google Drive folder are mainly jpg files, but other extensions should be recognized as well.
- The name of the file in the google drive is the same as the name in column BA (starting from row 3) and the google file link should be imported in column BB (starting from row 3).

I have checked similair scripts but because of my lack of experience, I could not figure it out how to make it work :(.

Who would be able to help me with a script?

Thank you so much!

I used this script, but removed the PDF. That broke it.

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssid')
  var nameSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var nameSheetData = []
  var pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderid");
  var folderIndex = pdfFolder.searchFiles("title contains 'pdf'");
  Logger.log(folderIndex)
  nameSheet.appendRow(['Name', 'Bank Book Photo']);
  while (folderIndex.hasNext()) {
    var file = folderIndex.next();
    var url = file.getUrl();
    var name = file.getName();
    nameSheet.appendRow([name, url]);
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI, this script is not Python.

Comment: @Codedabbler thankyou! That is how much I know of it :|

Comment: In terms of language, it is JavaScript (or Google Apps Script, if you prefer, without getting into the technicalities)

Comment: [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
function getFileLinks() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)
  var colStart = 53 // Column BA
  var colEnd = 54 // Column BB
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow()
  var rowStart = 2 // row 1 is a header

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(rowStart,colStart,lr-rowStart+1)
  var data = dataRange.getValues()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the data range = "+dataRange.getA1Notation())

  // loop through the file names in Column BA
  for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var fileName = data[i][0]
    var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName)

    // test for multiple copies
    var n=0;
    while(files.hasNext()) {
      var file=files.next();
      n++;
    }
    if (n== 1){
      var fileUrl = file.getUrl();
      Logger.log("DEBUG: i:"+i+", SINGLE: file name: "+fileName+" 1 file ONLY, URL: "+fileUrl)
      var formula = '=HYPERLINK("' + fileUrl + '","' + fileName + '")';
      sheet.getRange(+rowStart+i,colEnd).setFormula(formula);
    }
    else{
      Logger.log("DEBUG: i:"+i+", MULTIPLE: file name: "+fileName+" , #of files = "+n)
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Script Logic**

- assign some variables
- get the file names in Column BA
- loop through the file names

  - check whether there are any files with multiple copies of the same file
  - create a `HYPERLINK` formula using the file Name and URL
  - `setFormula` in column BB; the value of loop variable (`i`) PLUS `rowStart` (the first data row number) equals the row number.

---

**SAMPLE: Before**

[image: before]

---

**SAMPLE: After**

[image: after]

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all, it has been solved. I found a script online and with a little bit of tweaking, it does exactly what I needed :)

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Get Folder Details')
    .addItem('Retrieve Files', 'retrieveFiles')
    .addToUi();
}

function retrieveFiles() {
  var folderLink = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Paste this link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1J3qsMjFg9Rosuah_xJsrrGqWJrUcszRd?usp=drive_link').getResponseText();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(getFolderIdFromLink(folderLink));
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var data = [];
  
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileUrl = 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=' + file.getId();
    data.push([file.getName(), fileUrl]);
  }
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Files");
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Files retrieved successfully.');
}

function getFolderIdFromLink(link) {
  var regex = /\/folders\/([^/?]+)/;
  var match = link.match(regex);
  
  if (match && match[1]) {
    return match[1];
  }
  
  return null;
}
```